# echo specific part of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo

I'm still learning php arrays and I'm trying to echo a

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(9) "site_name" [1]=> string(3) "url" [2]=> string(5) "title" [3]=> string(11) "description" [4]=> string(4) "type" [5]=> string(5) "image" [6]=> string(11) "image:width" [7]=> string(12) "image:height" } NULL site_name => Playbuzzurl => http://www.playbuzz.com/jordonr10/what-modern-societal-archetype-fits-your-personalitytitle => What Modern Societal Archetype Fits Your Personality?description => It's 2017, so it's about time we update the books!type => articleimage => http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/aef166e1-1574-4d57-9823-3f38f30bcfc4/810f1d3e-0a97-4797-8235-b4c988562a1c.jpgimage:width => 1600image:height => 842
```

> array(8) { [0]=> string(9) "site_name" [1]=> string(3) "url" [2]=>
>   string(5) "title" [3]=> string(11) "description" [4]=> string(4)
>   "type" [5]=> string(5) "image" [6]=> string(11) "image:width" [7]=>
>   string(12) "image:height" } NULL site_name => Playbuzzurl =>
>   http://www.playbuzz.com/jordonr10/what-modern-societal-archetype-fits-your-personalitytitle
>   => What Modern Societal Archetype Fits Your Personality?description => It's 2017, so it's about time we update the books!type => articleimage
>   => http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/aef166e1-1574-4d57-9823-3f38f30bcfc4/810f1d3e-0a97-4797-8235-b4c988562a1c.jpgimage:width => 1600image:height => 842

I'm trying to echo just the value for `description` which is `It's 2017, so it's about time we update the books!`

I've tried several different things, but nothing works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
echo $array[0]['description'];      // returns nothing
var_dump($key);                     // returns string(12) "image:height"
```

**Current Code**

```
<?php
require_once('OpenGraph.php');

$graph = OpenGraph::fetch('http://www.playbuzz.com/jordonr10/what-modern-societal-archetype-fits-your-personality');
var_dump($graph->keys());
var_dump($graph->schema);

foreach ($graph as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value<br><hr>";
}
echo "Value Below<hr>";
echo $array['description'];

?>
```

Comment: the value of the description is outside of your array. You need to put it in an array first before you are able to get it.

Comment: show the code you used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code its seems that you can directly get value of description from `$graph` if key is already there.
 Also you are trying to diplay `$array['description'];`  here I can see $array is define any where

try to

```
 echo $graph['description']; // if $graph is array
```

OR

```
echo $graph->description; // If its an object
```

Comment: It is an Object. That explains why everything I was trying was failing. How do you tell the difference between object and array in the above? Thanks again!

Comment: Use `var_dump($graph);` The result will show you whether it is object or an array

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
echo $array[3];
```

Or use associative arrays which can be called

```
echo $array['description'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Hey justyand, Thanks for offering assistance. I did try both of those too, but neither work. Any other ideas?

Comment: No problem. First place your code. Then we can talk about malfunctioning. Basicaly first define an array, then call echo

Comment: @Mr.B your question doesn't make sense, read first comment under your question.

Comment: So from code it's obvious that **$array** is not defined
You have to use **$graph**